# Upgrade MongoDB meta-data after binary upgrade

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, metadata

I upgraded our MongoDB binaries from 2.2.5 to 2.4.9. I did not follow one of the considerations prior to upgrading:

- To upgrade to 2.4, sharded clusters must upgrade following the [meta-data upgrade](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/#meta-data-upgrade-procedure) procedure.

The reason, not that it matters, is because I didn't think it was needed since we do not have any sharded collections in our environment. So, instead of following the [sharded cluster upgrade](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/#upgrade-a-sharded-cluster-from-mongodb-2-2-to-mongodb-2-4), I followed the replica set upgrade procedure.

My question is, can I successfully run the meta-data upgrade without having to rollback to 2.2.5?

Comment: I've decided to rollback to 2.2.5 and perform the, then move to 2.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a sharded cluster the meta-data upgrade procedure from 2.2 to 2.4 is not required. It involves the config database which does not exist in a non-sharded environment.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted the question if it wasn't a sharded cluster.